# Incorrect syntax near '<'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, iif

I have a task to get some code which is working correctly on SQL Server 2012 to work on SQL Server 2008 R2 as well. I got this error:

> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '<'

When I try to run my code I found out that something is wrong in this line of my SQL code

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkTimeEntries] 
  ADD [TimeFinishedForRuntime] AS ISNULL([TimeFinished],
        IIF ([TimeStarted] < SYSUTCDATETIME(), [dbo].[udf_GetCurrentDateTimeOffsetInTimeZone](DATENAME(TZOFFSET, [TimeStarted])), [TimeStarted]));
```

I have read that in this cases took place some kind of error when people try to get date, but I'm not sure what's wrong in my case.

Comment: What SQL version are you running this on -- 2008 or 2012?  IIF() was not introduced until 2012.

Comment: I edit my post, my English is not good sorry. It's work good on SQL 2012, it's can't work on SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: No worries, Shnugo has answered you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was no `IIF` in SQL Server 2008R2.

Replace it with `CASE`

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkTimeEntries] ADD [TimeFinishedForRuntime] AS ISNULL(
    [TimeFinished],
    CASE WHEN [TimeStarted] < SYSUTCDATETIME() THEN [dbo].[udf_GetCurrentDateTimeOffsetInTimeZone](DATENAME(TZOFFSET, [TimeStarted])) ELSE [TimeStarted] END);
```

Comment: Oh thanks it works, but now i get another one error and i think its not a last one.
< Incorrect syntax near 'THROW'.
in this line
`BEGIN;
  THROW 50003, 'Inconsistent employee ids have been provided for TimeRegisteredEmployees', 1;
 END;`

Comment: @Stefan, same here... `THROW` was introduced with SQL Server 2012. Before `RAISERROR` was used. Find [details and a comparison here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx)

Comment: With your help i correct all errors without this one which I get on the end of my work
>Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'.
Whick take place in this line
~ISNULL(SUM(aed.[ActualMultiple]) OVER (PARTITION BY [WorkItemId] ORDER BY [TimeFinishedForRuntime] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING), 0) AS [GrossMultiple]
FROM [dbo].[BasicAggregatedWorkTimeEntriesView] wte
LEFT OUTER JOIN [AggregatedEmployeeData] aed ON wte.[Id] = aed.[WorkTimeEntryId];~

What i found out is that the ROWS are from SQL SERVER 2012 but i don't know how to replace it in my case.

Comment: @Stefan, here you are in troubles... the `SUM(...) OVER()` is used to calculate a cummulative SUM. This feature is quite new also... You might use something like `TimeFinishedForRuntime + (SELECT SUM(x.TimeFinishedForRuntime FROM dbo.WorkTimeEntries AS x WHERE xTimeStarted>TimeStarted))` Doing so, you would get for each of your rows a sum of all the older rows added to the actual value. But this is blind guessing...

Comment: We have to sum by Actual Multiple and i think We need there correlation with WorkItemId inside of WHERE.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, this error occurs if you any syntactical error in your SQL code. Please reverify all your statement sequence.